# How to run an array through a filter in js?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code.

```
var eqn = c1 + q1 + q2 +  ‘ + ‘ + c2 + w1 + w2 + ‘=‘ + c3 + e1 + e2;
```

***This code combines strings not add numbers.***

I think it would be best to modify this string by using an array which I can do. My question is I want to remove the variable if it equals 1. For example if `c1 == 1` then the variable should be defined like this: `var eqn = q1 + q2 +  ‘ + ‘ + c2 + w1 + w2 + ‘=‘ + c3 + e1 + e2;` I want this to happen to any one or more variable that is equal to one. Is there a function or piece of code that can be used to do this?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Sorry my mistake, take a look at the updated question

Comment: This will produce a syntax error..

Comment: @webdeb What do you mean?

Comment: there is + operator missing, and btw. what are you doing? concatenating stirngs or adding numbers? If this is a mix, it will end up in an unexpected result: `2 + 2 + " + " + 3 + 3` check your console..

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token. The ‘ symbol doesn't mean anything in javascript. If you mean a single quotation mark then you're still missing a plus sign. This question is really ambiguous. Are you adding numbers or concatenating strings. You shouldn't use `string` as a variable name because its reserved. There are many other reasons why this deserves to be downvoted. The question isn't even clearly stated.

Comment: Use parentheses to make it clear and better readable: 
`(2 + 2) + " + " + (3 + 3)`

Comment: @webdeb I am not adding numbers but combining strings.

Comment: @Octopus I am concatenating strings, and I have changed the variable namme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var string = [c1, q1, q2, ' + ', c2, w1, w2, ' = ', c3, e1, e2]
  .reduce((acc, cur) => cur == 1 ? acc : acc + '' + cur, '');
```

Example:

The following values

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ' + ' + 4 + 5 + 6 + ' = ' + 7 + 8 + 9;
```

will return

```
'23 + 456 = 789'
```

Comment: Very pretty! But maybe make sure you coerce it to a string or c1 and q1 will add mathematically. ...? acc : '' + acc + cur

Comment: @klugjo Does that mean when I run console.log(string); will I get one fluent string?

Comment: That's nice!  I would have `filter`ed then `join`ed.  I like your method though.

Comment: would't it be prefixed with "undefined", you should probably define the initial acc.

Comment: @klugjo q1, w1, and e1 are letters/words, would this method still work?

Comment: Sorry; I don't think the output includes the '1', right? (I tried to edit the answer but it wouldn't let me only edit 1 character. :-? )

Comment: Edited my answer. '1' is not included in the question either. To make it work just replace the `===` with `==`

Comment: (Oh, I didn't see that but you're right. I meant that '123 + 456 = 789' should be just '23 + 456 = 789'.)

Answer (score 0):

OK so under the assumption that the variables are numeric you could run them all through a function such as the following, which will return zero if it contains one, and the arithmetic will work out:

```
function excludeIfOne(val) {
    return val === 1 ? 0 : val
}
```

This could however lead to one long messy line of code.  See the other answer suggesting the use of `reduce`, which I was about to suggest myself

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), you can using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).(likes klugjo's way)

```
var string = [c1, q1, q2, ' + ', c2, w1, w2, '+', c3, e1, e2];
string.filter(word=> word!=1).join('');
```

Comment: typo: use `filter` instead of `map`

Comment: Thanks for indicating my fault.